# Approximation algorithms for indefinite quadratic form maximization with linear constraints

Tags: approximation, quadratic-programming

Consider the following program:
\begin{align}
\max_x ~& x^TQx
\\ \mbox{s.t.} ~& Ax \geq b
\end{align}
where $Q$ is a symmetric (possibly indefinite) matrix and the inequality is element-wise and constrains feasible solutions to a convex polytope.

This is NP-hard to solve, but **what are known approximation results?**

A relevant result is given by [(Kough 1979)](http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&profile=ehost&scope=site&authtype=crawler&jrnl=0030364X&AN=4475340&h=jvzqWGD93FupTVzmsdYpOkIcP4LcfEtYiQUXmpjDdnRvEOR2pFpz%2FYemLSy1JlMChDLASelPmLhB91UFHi8biw%3D%3D&crl=f). It is shown that this program can be optimized using Benders' decomposition to within $\epsilon$ of the optimum. However, the paper does not seem to clearly specify what this means, or the complexity of the procedure.

I believe the $\epsilon$-approximation is in the usual sense employed in the field of mathematical programming, that is, if $OPT$ is the optimal value of the program, $ALG$ is the result of the above procedure and $MIN$ is the minimal value attainable by a feasible solution,
$$
\frac{ALG-MIN}{OPT-MIN} \geq (1-\epsilon).
$$
Or something of the sort.

Questions:

- Is the mentioned procedure a polynomial-time algorithm?
- Are there known polynomial-time algorithms yielding approximations to the above program in the traditional sense, i.e. $ALG \geq \alpha OPT $ for some $\alpha < 1$, constant or not.

> **Update**: I don't think it's possible to get an $\alpha OPT$ approximation for general quadratic programming for a very simple
>   reason: in negative definite instances, the optimum is negative.
>
> Still, it would be interesting to know if approximations are possible
>   when the quadratic form is nonegative in the feasible set. Also, it
>   would be nice to know the complexity of the Bender's decomposition
>   method.

-

> Kough, Paul F. "The indefinite quadratic programming problem."
>   Operations Research 27.3 (1979): 516-533.